# Error during MGRS conversion for large latitudes

Tags: coordinate-system, java, latitude-longitude, mgrs, worldwind

I'm using Nasa's Worldwind java API to convert MGRS strings to lat/lon. However, when my latitude is greater than 85 degrees or less than -85 degrees I get an error.
 `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error during MGRS conversion`

Here is my input

```
MGRSCoord.fromString("ZAD 00000 66856", null);
```

I'm creating the MGRS from worldwind was well.

```
Double latitude = 87.0;
Double longitude = 0.0;
Angle latitudeAngle = Angle.fromDegreesLatitude(latitude);
Angle longitudeAngle = Angle.fromDegreesLongitude(longitude);
String coordString = MGRSCoord.fromLatLon(latitudeAngle,longitudeAngle).toString();
MGRSCoord.fromString(coordString, null);
```

My guest guess is this is frdefault `Globe` into the conversion by using `null`, but I tried using actual `Globe`s, but it didn't work, and frankly I didn't really know what to set it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that conversion actually goes
LatLng <==> UTM <==> MGRS

Since UTM is defined as valid for latitudes from 80°S to 84°N, the conversion fails.

Comment: Looking at the code [here](https://github.com/NASAWorldWind/WorldWindJava/blob/v2.0.0/src/gov/nasa/worldwind/geom/coords/MGRSCoordConverter.java) the conversion is done in the method `convertMGRSToGeodetic` where they first convert to UTM. They have a line `// TODO: polar conversion`. So I guess polar conversion isn't supported. I wish somewhere in their documentation it said that. Thanks